# Turing machines, thinking and category mistakes

Tags: logic, reference-request, artificial-intelligence

According to my recollection, some philosophers have argued that it is a category mistake to ascribe intelligence to Turing machines, because Turing machines are abstract mathematical objects.

What are some classical references, if any?

Comment: The first reference is Turing's paper https://academic.oup.com/mind/article/LIX/236/433/986238

Comment: @JoWehler Turing does not use the term "category mistakes" in his paper, and he does not include category mistakes amongst the 9 objections to thinking machines which he considers in section 6 of his paper.

Comment: @JoWehler One should bear in mind that footnote 3, in the article Category Mistake, of the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, Gilbert Ryles book The Concept of Mind, 1949, states: "This seems to be the first time the concept of a category mistake is referred to using this label.” Given this, it is not a surprise that Turing did not consider the problem.

Comment: AI enthusiasts also ascribe intelligence to algorithms, which are also abstract mathematical objects. It is a form of Platonism and is closely related to numerology; both involve the ascription of causal powers to abstract objects. I mean Platonism in the sense of Plato and his Ideal Forms, not the new sense which is just the position that abstract objects exist.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Is there interesting work being done by such AI enthusiasts?

Comment: according to Aristotle intelligence is a part of the human soul, see his work for more information about it